# Netbeans doesn't run and doesn't deploy my Java EE project

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, deployment, glassfish

I started with Java development. I created  a JavaEE + primefaces application. I’m using Netbeans 7.1 and GlassFish 3.1.1
When I do the "run" or "deploy" on the project, Netbeans hangs at the stage

"Completed initial distribution of [project_name]", but the run don't complete  :(

However, when the deploy the ear directly from the GlassFish admin, deployment is running well.
What to do? How to proceed?

Comment: Could you provide some more information. Is it a maven project? How do you build the ear/war that you can successfully deploy? Are you using the bundle glassfish in both scenarios? If not, let us know your setup.

Comment: @esej Thanks for concern. Not it's not a maven projects, it's a EJB + Primeface project. The ear which works is generated throws the "clean and build" menu in Netbeans. I'm using a slandalone glassFish server (not the one embedded in Netbeans). I added that standalone GF as a server in my Netbeans. Sorry if my english is not good. I usually speak french